# How to reduce GIF size?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is my code to Create Gif file however the Gif file which it is producing has a size of 4.9 MB and it contain 32 frames

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    String dstFile = "result.gif";
    final String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + dstFile;
    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;
    int delayMs = 100;

    GifEncoder gifEncoder = new GifEncoder();

    try {
        gifEncoder.init(width, height, filePath, GifEncoder.EncodingType.ENCODING_TYPE_NORMAL_LOW_MEMORY);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    gifEncoder.setDither(true);

     ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     byte[] Byte;

    Bitmap resized;
    int j;
    for ( j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
        Utilities.BoomerangeFrames[j].compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP,20,bos);
        Byte = bos.toByteArray();
        resized = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(Byte,0,Byte.length);
        resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( Utilities.BoomerangeFrames[j], width, height, true);
        gifEncoder.encodeFrame(resized, delayMs);
        bos.reset();
    }
    gifEncoder.close();
    return null;
}
```

}

I want to know is there any solution to reduce my gif file size upto 1 MB.

Answer (score 0):

You can decrease color depth of you image like in this [article](https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/image-processing-decreasing-color-depth/) but you loose quality ,because this simple method not using adaptive color palette. May be good idea stored file in video format with MediaCodec API.